# Draw line from Player to Mouse position (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, line, raycasting

When i press LMB i am rotating my player towards the mouse position, what i also want to do is simulate shooting. So when clicking LMB i want to create a line from the player position to the mouse position. My big issue is that my player is moving and i cant seem to figure out how to get the start position of the ray.

As of now the ray renders from vector3(0,0,0) to the mouse position, which is not what i want. I want it to render from the PLAYER position to the mouse position.

Here is my code:

```
 void Update () {

 transform.Translate (Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed, Space.World);

 if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) {

     Vector3 mousePos = new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 10);
     Vector3 lookPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mousePos);
     lookPos = lookPos - transform.position;
     float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (lookPos.y, lookPos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + 90;
     transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (angle, Vector3.forward);

     if (Time.time > nextFire) 
     {
         nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
         StartCoroutine (shotEffect());
         laserLine.SetPosition (1,this.transform.position+lookPos);            
     }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is attached to player and laserLine.SetPosition() sets beginning and ending for your line i think that:

```
laserLine.SetPosition (1,this.transform.position+lookPos);
```

should looks:

```
laserLine.SetPosition (this.transform.position,this.transform.position+lookPos);
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Line renderers take two arguments: the first is a reference to an array that stores positions, and the second is the Vector3 of where you want that point to be. Using a Vector3 as the first argument throws an error.